# Postback on second click of button in UpdatePanel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am creating a page in asp.net where an update panel is added dynamically, and few controls(button,table) are created and added to update panel dynamically.

Below is the piece of code:

```
  UpdatePanel up = new UpdatePanel();
                    up.ID = newRequests.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString() + "up" + i.ToString();
                    up.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Always;
                    // create table
                    HtmlGenericControl table=new HtmlGenericControl("table");
                    HtmlTableRow toprow = new HtmlTableRow();

                    HtmlTableCell topleftcell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    HtmlTableCell toprightcell = new HtmlTableCell();



                    // create button
                    Button add = new Button();
                    add.Text = "Approve";
                    add.ID = newRequests.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString() + "btn" + i.ToString();
                   toprightcell.Controls.Add(add);
                    toprightcell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));


                    // add trigger to update panel

                    AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
                    trigger.ControlID = add.ID;
                    trigger.EventName = "Click";
                    up.Triggers.Add(trigger); 

                    toprow.Controls.Add(topleftcell);
                    toprow.Controls.Add(toprightcell);
                    table.Controls.Add(toprow);
                    up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(table);
                    div.Controls.Add(up);

                    divNR.Add(div);
```

Below is div tag where update panel is added dynamically.

```
   <div id="div_AMContainer" runat="server" class="panelContainer">


    </div>
```

**Problem is:**

When I click on button first time, there is no postback.
But on second click, page is reloaded.

Am I missing something here.?

Comment: share also tag of your button.

Comment: button is also created dynamically and added in update panel. Please check "// create button" part in posted code.

Comment: Yes, you are missing that the button click event is triggered after the postback (so when you click on the button, you run the page_load is postback, then once the page is loaded it runs the button_click event and adds the dynamic stuff, then on the next postback it will load that stuff nad you iwll be able to see it)

Comment: @Innat. How do I fix that? Cutteently I have not added any event on that button.

Comment: @DKR I'm not an asp expert myself, but you could set a (e.g. boolean type) variable when you click on the button, and manage the adding of the dynamic stuff depending on its value during the page_load. But perharps there are more elegant alternatives using other page events such as Page_PreRender, but alas, I have not played with those enough so as to advise you